# expected primary-expression before 'double'

Tags: c++, arduino

Im trying to create a PID controller:

```
PID* nsController = new PID(&double(imu.ypr[2]*), &nsOut, 
                             &nsSet, 7, 0.0, 1.1, REVERSE);

error: expected primary-expression before 'double'
```

`imu.ypr` is `float ypr[3]`;
PID canditates are: `PID::PID(double*, double*, double*, double, double, double, int)`

what does that error mean? and how to fix? Im just trying to convert `float` to `double`. 
What does the `*` and & mean? Thank you

Comment: The syntax you're using is wrong for the first parameter.

Comment: Can you help me to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't take the address of a temporary like that.

Instead, create a new local variable and pass that in:

```
double val = imu.ypr[2];
PID* nsController = new PID(&val, &nsOut, 
                         &nsSet, 7, 0.0, 1.1, REVERSE);
```